# Error when opening .app in iOS Simulator with Xcode 11.2

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode11

Xcode Version: 11.2
iOS simulator version used: 13.2 and 12.4

Installed .app via drag and drop to iOS simulator but when I try to open it I get this error. This method was fine when my Xcode is still v10. [image]

Comment: Xcode was updated to Xcode 11.2.1. Maybe because of that?

Answer (score 1):

try to download old Xcode 10 and test your app.
https://developer.apple.com/download/more/
hope it helps to find the bug

Answer (score 0):

Installed Xcode 10 (Thanks Vlad Tagunkov) and changed the Command Line Tools to v10.3[image]

Also, this only works with iOS 12.4 simulator. Tried it on 13.2 and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

you need to see what you have in log. turn logging mode in most detail mode and run the app.
you will probably see where the problem.
hope it helps.